# Push Notifications when app is closed, WakefulBroadcastReceiver not running In android 6

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can receive push notification when my app is in foreground or background
I added FcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver in order to get push
when I close my application.
But I continue without receiving notifications when the app is closed.
Thanks for your help.

manifest.xml

```
<pre>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <permission android:name="<package>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
            <receiver
                android:name="<package>.Notification.FcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <category android:name="<package>" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

<service android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>


public class FcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.e("receiver","okey");
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}





public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    Intent i;
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        System.out.println("******************** +  getMessageType "+remoteMessage.getMessageType());
        System.out.println("******************** +  getFrom "+remoteMessage.getFrom());
        System.out.println("******************** +  getMessageId "+remoteMessage.getMessageId());
        System.out.println("******************** +  getTo "+remoteMessage.getTo());
        System.out.println("******************** +  getData "+remoteMessage.getData());
        System.out.println("******************** +  getData().get(message) "+remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        System.out.println("******************** +  getData().get(title) "+remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));


        showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("type"),remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());




    }



    private void showNotification(String to , String title, String message) {


        i = new Intent(this,ProfileActivity.class);

        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(0,builder.build());
    }

}

<code>
```

Comment: You have to include `data payload` to trigger `onMessageReceived` and rise notification if you want to do that when app is in background, and for that you need custom server side logic as that is not possible from firebase console but luckly for you there are tutorials how to do that.

Comment: i have onMessageReceived , i added the code to my question

Comment: This tutorial will work for you: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/
And here you have custom made php server from where you can send notfications:
http://demo.androidhive.info/firebase/notifications/

Comment: Push notification when app is closed is not running on android 6 , for fewer version it works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

The issue that I can see in your code is that you are implementing the FireBase push notification but you are trying to implement that in a way that was used to implement GCM. You don't need to set any Broadcast Receivers, Firebase is doing that by itself. You just have to run "FirebaseMessagingService". The services looks like this:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
    // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated.
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
}
```

As you can see it has it's own "onMessageReceived" method that takes care of Broadcast Receiver's functionality.

Check this tutorial, it will help you to understand:

https://www.codementor.io/flame3/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase-du10860kb

Note: If you want your app to work in each situation even app is in background, foreground or even closed then you need to send some data through payload in your notification.then it will work for all conditions. To do that you need your own server, Firebase doesn't facilitate for that.

Comment: `notification messages` will not trigger `onMessageReceived` as they will be displayed in the system tray if your app is in background instead you have to pass `data payload`. And note: sending that kind of messages is not possible through firebase console as `data` keyword needs to be included. In another words your answer will not work either.

Comment: Thanks @Yupi for the clarification, but in that case when you will click on the notification it will still take you to the app and in your Activity you can get values through "intent.getExtras()". That whole scenario is also described in Firebase Documents, that link is provided in the end of tutorial as well. But I don't think this guy needs any extra values and I was just trying to give him the basic idea.

Comment: I added MyFirebaseMessagingService..class.

Comment: the push push runs well when my app is in background , the problem is when the app is fully closed

Comment: As mentioned above in Yupi's comment you need to send some data in notification through your own server. In that case your notification will be triggered in each scenario even when your app is in background/killed. And also please note you need your own server to customize notification data because Firebase doesn't facilitate for that.

Comment: I have my own server, and i'm sending both data object, and notification object.

Comment: Push notification when app is closed is not running on android 6 , for fewer version it works like a charm

Comment: It shouldn't be having issue with Android version, please try to test it on any other device with version Android 6.

Comment: Ah okey, it works with sumsung android 6 , the problem comes with HUAWEI P8 lite.

Comment: There must be some issue with this specific device, try to test it on another P9 or restart your phone.or delete some apps from it.Or try to uninstall this app from your phone and install it again.